# Express.js : get req.body.datas of an same source iframe

Tags: javascript, express, iframe, server, sequelize.js

Because its a bad practice to nest forms, i made an internal iframe from my website source that load another form. Because its internal i have add styles and everything, but when posting trough express (i also use sequelize to create my entities), even if the return page is loaded, my data are empty. Is something that i miss ? Maybe i must specified req.accepts(), i'm asking if someone is aware about this kind of problems.

```
app.post('/sendOwners', function (req, res) {
  ownerController
//these are empty even filled from the front end
     .create(req, res, req.body.name,req.body.firstname, req.body.civility) 
     .then(function(owner){
        res.send('contenu owner' +owner +'contenu req:'+req.body)
     })
})
```

my iframe

```
  <iframe id="iframeID"
          name="_parent"
          sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin"
          src="owners"
   ></iframe>
```

Comment: maybe the question is : how to parse data from iframe using express ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a clear response about this subject on the web. I had to find a way, after hours i finally change method form to 'get' and used req.query to access my datas. It seems to work now.